# How to use filter from an array while fetching graphql query and also must keep the array order?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to filter a result using an array and it should follow the order of the filter array.

Here's my array which will be used for filtering.

```
// gatsby-node.js

// Fetch all collections
  const collections = await graphql(`
    {
      allContentfulCollection {
        edges {
          node {
            handle
            productLists {
              slug
              handles
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  collections.data.allContentfulCollection.edges.forEach((collection) => {
    const { handle, productLists } = collection.node;

    if (productLists.length) {
      const defaultList = productLists.find(
        (productList) => productList.slug === 'default'
      );

      // example defaultList.handles =
      // [
      //  'test-handle-a',
      //  'test-handle-b',
      //  'test-handle-c',
      //  'test-handle-d'
      // ];

      createPage({
        path: `/collections/${handle}`,
        component: path.resolve('./src/templates/collection.js'),
        context: {
          handle,
          handles: defaultList && defaultList.handles // this will be used to filter
        }
      });
    }
  });
...
```

```
// templates/collection.js
export const query = graphql`
  query ProductInCollection($handles: [String], $handle: String) {
    allContentfulProduct(filter: { handle: { in: $handles }, availableForSale: { eq: true } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          handle
        }
      }
    }
    ...
```

The graphql result does not follow the sort of `$handles` array.

For example, the handle field which I get like the image is

[image]

```
[
  'test-handle-b', // this is matching result with test-handle-a
  'test-handle-d', // ...
  'test-handle-c', // ...
  'test-handle-a', // ...
]

// I expect to get the query result with the same order to the `$handles` in the query filter like below.

[
  'test-handle-a',
  'test-handle-b',
  'test-handle-c',
  'test-handle-d'
]
```

As you can see, I want to follow the ordering of the `handles` array, but I get an unexpected result like the above example.

How can I get the result with sort of the `handles` array?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It should take the filter order as it is. Are you sure that it **always** has the same order? Does it always contain the same information in the same order? Do they have any rules that you can use to sort them?

In your case, I'd try:

```
  createPage({
    path: `/collections/${handle}`,
    component: path.resolve('./src/templates/collection.js'),
    context: {
      handle,
      handles.sort() // add an specific rule if any
    }
  });
```

Moreover, you can try sorting the output via GraphQL [`sort`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#sort):

```
// templates/collection.js
export const query = graphql`
  query ProductInCollection($handles: [String], $handle: String) {
    allContentfulProduct(filter: { handle: { in: $handles }, availableForSale: { eq: true } }, sort: { fields: [handle, $handles], order: ASC }) {
      edges {
        node {
          description
          handle
          title
        }
      }
    }
    ...
```

Despite adding the sorting in the GraphQL or JavaScript logic, I'd ensure that it has always the exact order. Additionally, if you can access the source of that array, you can try adding an `order` field to each array element.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my question. I don't want to sort the `handles` array, just want to get the query result based on the sort of the `handles` array.

Comment: Please check my question again. I just made some updates.

Comment: I got the question but I lack from where you get that array. The array is listed as is to the template so, if for example, the array comes from an external source, it may appear with a different sorting each time. In addition, you can sort the array before lifting it to the template to ensure that it comes with your desired sorting, that's why I asked if you have any specific rule for sorting (ending with a number or something like this)

Comment: Please check the image just attached.

Comment: I believe the sort of the `handles` array doesn't change, it is fixed always.

Comment: I think there's a part of code missing (what's `collections? It's an alias?). I think that everything goes as expected, the problem is that your `handle` is not in order, so it filters: it searches for `handle-b` in a sorted array, but because of it's the first element to be filtered, it appears in the first position

Comment: So the backend should filter the query result in the correct order?

Comment: I don't know your implementation details. This is an option. Another one is to treat the data before looping through the collection to sort it as you wish